# Enabling Foreign Key Support for SQlite on VB Net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Following this tutorial http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html I need a database with 3 tables but a I can't fix a message about "SQL logic error.... near Foreign"

```
Private Sub CreateDataBase()

    Dim conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDataBase.sqlite;Version=3")

    Try
        Using (conn)
            conn.Open()


            '3 Tables I need to create
            Dim mainTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(20))"
            Dim tableA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA (ItemA VARCHAR(20), user INTEGER) FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES users (userID)"
            Dim tableB = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableB (ItemB VARCHAR(20), user INTEGER) FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES users (userID)"

            Dim cmdConexion As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(mainTable, conn)


    'Try for the mainTable
            Try
                cmdConexion.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try


    'Set and Try for tableA
            cmdConexion.CommandText = tableA
            Try
                cmdConexion.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try


    'Set and Try for tableB
            cmdConexion.CommandText = tableB

            Try
                cmdConexion.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
```

The same code works fine for only the mainTable.

I tryed with a line like

```
Pragma("foreign_keys") = 1
```

or even

```
cmdConexion.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"
```

but still I can´t fix the error.

**Where is the error on the SQL line or on the Pragma on?**

Note:
Also, is there another way to execute the SQL Create Table on the same Try - Catch or is better one Try - Catch for each table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error int the CREATE TABLE statement. The [FOREIGN KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_basics)-part must be within the parentheses

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA (
    ItemA VARCHAR(20),
    user INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES users (userID)
)
```

or simply

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableA (
    ItemA VARCHAR(20),
    user INTEGER REFERENCES users (userID)
)
```

Note: an err like "... near something" is often just a syntax error.

Comment: Right!! Both solutions worked! My mistake was one ")" out of place. Thanks for the other tip